# Загрузка изображений на сайт в комментариях

Tags: wordpress, изображения, комментарии

Всем привет.У меня есть сайт на wordpress с подключенной темой oceanwp.В этой теме комментарии можно оставлять только в текстовом формате.Так вот вопрос могу ли я добавить возможность загружать не только текст, но и изображения? И что я должен буду поменять в коде?Заранее спасибо.

```
 <?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Comments.
 *
 * The area of the page that contains both current comments and the comment
 * form. The actual display of comments is handled by a callback to
 * oceanwp_comment() which is located at functions/comments-callback.php
 *
 * @package OceanWP WordPress theme
 */

// Return if password is required
if ( post_password_required() ) {
    return;
}

// Add classes to the comments main wrapper
$classes = 'comments-area clr';

if ( get_comments_number() != 0 ) {
    $classes .= ' has-comments';
}

if ( ! comments_open() && get_comments_number() < 1 ) {
    $classes .= ' empty-closed-comments';
    return;
}

if ( 'full-screen' == oceanwp_post_layout() ) {
    $classes .= ' container';
} ?>

<section id="comments" class="<?php echo esc_attr( $classes ); ?>">

    <?php // You can start editing here -- including this comment! ?>

    <?php if ( have_comments() ) :

        // Get comments title
        $comments_number = number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() );
        if ( '1' == $comments_number ) {
            $comments_title = esc_html__( 'This Post Has One Comment', 'oceanwp' );
        } else {
            $comments_title = sprintf( esc_html__( 'This Post Has %s Comments', 'oceanwp' ), $comments_number );
        }
        $comments_title = apply_filters( 'ocean_comments_title', $comments_title ); ?>

        <h3 class="theme-heading comments-title">
            <span class="text"><?php echo esc_html( $comments_title ); ?></span>
        </h3>

        <ol class="comment-list">
            <?php
            // List comments
            wp_list_comments( array(
                'callback'  => 'oceanwp_comment',
                'style'     => 'ol',
                'format'    => 'html5',
            ) ); ?>
        </ol><!-- .comment-list -->

        <?php
        // Display comment navigation - WP 4.4.0
        if ( function_exists( 'the_comments_navigation' ) ) :

            the_comments_navigation( array(
                'prev_text' => '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>'. esc_html__( 'Previous', 'oceanwp' ),
                'next_text' => esc_html__( 'Next', 'oceanwp' ) .'<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>',
            ) );

        elseif ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) : ?>

            <div class="comment-navigation clr">
                <?php paginate_comments_links( array(
                    'prev_text' => '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>'. esc_html__( 'Previous', 'oceanwp' ),
                    'next_text' => esc_html__( 'Next', 'oceanwp' ) .'<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>',
                ) ); ?>
            </div>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php
        // Display comments closed message
        if ( ! comments_open() && get_comments_number() ) : ?>
            <p class="no-comments"><?php esc_html_e( 'Comments are closed.' , 'oceanwp' ); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endif; // have_comments() ?>

    <?php
    comment_form(
        array(
            'must_log_in'           => '<p class="must-log-in">'.  sprintf( esc_html__( 'You must be %1$slogged in%2$s to post a comment.', 'oceanwp' ), '<a href="'. wp_login_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink() ) ) .'">', '</a>' ) .'</p>',
            'logged_in_as'          => '<p class="logged-in-as">'. esc_html__( 'Logged in as', 'oceanwp' ) .' <a href="'. admin_url( 'profile.php' ) .'">'. $user_identity .'</a>. <a href="' . wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ) .'" title="'. esc_html__( 'Log out of this account', 'oceanwp' ) .'">'. esc_html__( 'Log out &raquo;', 'oceanwp' ) .'</a></p>',
            'comment_notes_before'  => false,
            'comment_notes_after'   => false,
            'comment_field'         => '<div class="comment-textarea"><textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="39" rows="4" tabindex="100" class="textarea-comment" placeholder="'. esc_html__( 'Your Comment Here...', 'oceanwp' ) .'"></textarea></div>',
            'id_submit'             => 'comment-submit',
            'label_submit'          => esc_html__( 'Post Comment', 'oceanwp' ),
        )
    ); ?>

</section><!-- #comments -->



     <?php
    /**
     * The template for displaying Comments.
     *
     * The area of the page that contains both current comments and the comment
     * form. The actual display of comments is handled by a callback to
     * oceanwp_comment() which is located at functions/comments-callback.php
     *
     * @package OceanWP WordPress theme
     */

    // Return if password is required
    if ( post_password_required() ) {
     return;
    }

    // Add classes to the comments main wrapper
    $classes = 'comments-area clr';

    if ( get_comments_number() != 0 ) {
     $classes .= ' has-comments';
    }

    if ( ! comments_open() && get_comments_number() < 1 ) {
     $classes .= ' empty-closed-comments';
     return;
    }

    if ( 'full-screen' == oceanwp_post_layout() ) {
     $classes .= ' container';
    } ?>

    <section id="comments" class="<?php echo esc_attr( $classes ); ?>">

     <?php // You can start editing here -- including this comment! ?>

     <?php if ( have_comments() ) :

      // Get comments title
      $comments_number = number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() );
      if ( '1' == $comments_number ) {
       $comments_title = esc_html__( 'This Post Has One Comment', 'oceanwp' );
      } else {
       $comments_title = sprintf( esc_html__( 'This Post Has %s Comments', 'oceanwp' ), $comments_number );
      }
      $comments_title = apply_filters( 'ocean_comments_title', $comments_title ); ?>

      <h3 class="theme-heading comments-title">
       <span class="text"><?php echo esc_html( $comments_title ); ?></span>
      </h3>

      <ol class="comment-list">
       <?php
       // List comments
       wp_list_comments( array(
        'callback'  => 'oceanwp_comment',
        'style'     => 'ol',
        'format'    => 'html5',
       ) ); ?>
      </ol><!-- .comment-list -->

      <?php
      // Display comment navigation - WP 4.4.0
      if ( function_exists( 'the_comments_navigation' ) ) :

       the_comments_navigation( array(
        'prev_text' => '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>'. esc_html__( 'Previous', 'oceanwp' ),
        'next_text' => esc_html__( 'Next', 'oceanwp' ) .'<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>',
       ) );

      elseif ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) : ?>

       <div class="comment-navigation clr">
        <?php paginate_comments_links( array(
         'prev_text' => '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>'. esc_html__( 'Previous', 'oceanwp' ),
         'next_text' => esc_html__( 'Next', 'oceanwp' ) .'<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>',
        ) ); ?>
       </div>

      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php
      // Display comments closed message
      if ( ! comments_open() && get_comments_number() ) : ?>
       <p class="no-comments"><?php esc_html_e( 'Comments are closed.' , 'oceanwp' ); ?></p>
      <?php endif; ?>

     <?php endif; // have_comments() ?>

     <?php
     comment_form(
      array(
       'must_log_in'   => '<p class="must-log-in">'.  sprintf( esc_html__( 'You must be %1$slogged in%2$s to post a comment.', 'oceanwp' ), '<a href="'. wp_login_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink() ) ) .'">', '</a>' ) .'</p>',
       'logged_in_as'   => '<p class="logged-in-as">'. esc_html__( 'Logged in as', 'oceanwp' ) .' <a href="'. admin_url( 'profile.php' ) .'">'. $user_identity .'</a>. <a href="' . wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ) .'" title="'. esc_html__( 'Log out of this account', 'oceanwp' ) .'">'. esc_html__( 'Log out &raquo;', 'oceanwp' ) .'</a></p>',
       'comment_notes_before' => false,
       'comment_notes_after' => false,
       'comment_field'   => '<div class="comment-textarea"><textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="39" rows="4" tabindex="100" class="textarea-comment" placeholder="'. esc_html__( 'Your Comment Here...', 'oceanwp' ) .'"></textarea></div>',
       'id_submit'    => 'comment-submit',
       'label_submit'   => esc_html__( 'Post Comment', 'oceanwp' ),
      )
     ); ?>

    </section><!-- #comments -->
```

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/dco-comment-attachment/ и др

Comment: Большое спасибо тебе, чувак, очень помог